# haskell, typing with ordering

Tags: haskell, hugs

I have one problem. I want to implement function which will compare two nodes and give ordering,where nodes the following structure:

```
data Node a = Node { label :: a, adjacent :: [(a,Int)] } deriving Show


sortNode:: Node a->Node a->Ordering
sortNode node1 node2
    | takeLabel node1 > takeLabel node2 = GT
    | takeLabel node1 < takeLabel node2 = LT
    | takeLabel node1 == takeLabel node2 = EQ
```

hugs complain about this

```
ERROR "Network.hs":35 - Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding
*** Expression    : sortNode
*** Type          : Node a -> Node a -> Ordering
*** Given context : ()
*** Constraints   : Ord a
```

can you explain?(i am beginner in haskell)

Comment: Try adding an `Ord a` constraint like this: `sortNode :: (Ord a) => Node a -> Node a -> Ordering`.

Comment: I think this question is better fit for [__Code Review__](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: Code Review is for working code only, see their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: takeLabel gives label of Node

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, yes it works. Can you explain me why it worked

Comment: @nuraureum Instead of `takeLabel` you can simply use `label` then, which you've already declared with the record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type signature for *sortNode* specifies an empty context but (<) and (>) require that type *a* is an instance of class **Ord** and (==) requires that it is an instance of class **Eq**. You need to add a constraint to the context as Nikita suggested or omit the explicit type signature and the interpreter will be able to infer it.

```
sortNode :: (Ord a) => Node a -> Node a -> Ordering
```